# Is Text Preprocessing necessary for BERT Models?

Tags: text, bert-language-model, data-preprocessing

I get more efficient results when I cluster my data without text preprocessing with a model of the BERT model trained for Turkish. I would be very grateful if you could give me information on the reason for this. Thank you very much.